# Not able to drag and drop from Data source to Form in WInform in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dataset, datasource

[image]Folks

I have a dataset table in Data Source in VS 2010 which I just created. However I am not able to drag and drop this to winform in VS 2010 :( I configured the datasource as "DataGrid". Nothing happens :( Please help
My try:
[image]
I have put the picture here. Please if any one folk couldn't understand what I mean, please see the picture. In that picture, the developer just configured left side DS under DS as Datagrid and dragged and dropped to the right side form. It then automatically created a dg in rightside with all toolbars shown. I am not able to drag and drop, wondering whats the problem.

Comment: Could someone please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to drag n drop dataset from toolbox? Does it shows "Add dataset" dialog? Or, if you want data grid, you can drop DataGridView component from toolbox - and set data source for it

Comment: Jleru, no no, I have a DS in VS 2010 and I have a Dataset in that Data Source. I am trying to configure it as Datagrid and drop it in Windows form and just run the app, it should show me the table data as configured in dataset. Its done in a video and I am trying to replicate. But in the video he uses Visual Studio 2005 express. I use VS 2010. Is there any difference ?

Comment: Not one folk here who are .NET Developers know the answer for it or could help ?

Comment: Can you give us a link to the video? If possible.

Comment: @DePeter: No it was given as compliments CD for beginners of .NET during a conference in 2005 when I was in college. I have posted the above picture. Where you can see the datagrid in the right side which he dropped from the left side  customer dataset :( He used vs 2005 express. I am using vs 2010 ultimate. I am learning :( I am upset now and demotivated and stopped learning :(

Comment: I tried various ways, but couldn't figure out the reason for dysfunctioning :( I am demotivated....

Comment: If you are still learning I suggest that you get up to date and find some tutorials for Visual Studio 2010 which will be of much more use to you and your career. Databinding using the designer has changed a lot over the years and the video you are using is simply out of date and no longer usefull. There are millions of tutorials freely available on the web that can help you further. Good luck, and don't give up so easily!

Comment: @DePeter: Uhmm :( Ok Well I didn't see any much videos for free through net and neither my internet bandwidth is good enough to let me view videos which is buffering free :( I got these 2 cds which are exactly the way one can understand by Bob Tabor of http://LearnVisualStudio.NET   And yeah I am not pretty new to programming, but have good background knowledge and so these videos help me. I understood and achieved almost what he said except for the drag and drop :( Thank you so much for replying, I appreciate it. I will not give up, will continue to learn. Have good time buddy :) Cheers

Comment: @DePeter: Today I achieved drag and drop. Not sure whether it is my luck/fate or its MS in-consistency problem. I just woke up this morning and used this VS 2010 which was unclosed in my lappy, then tried drag and drop by seeing it. It has created things that was in there in the video :) Morning always rocks :) Cheers thank you Peter :)

Comment: @Divine glad you stuck through and got the drag and drop working! Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To drag and drop fields from your data source directly into your form in C#, do the following:

1. Create a C# windows forms project.
2. Select the form by clicking it and go to properties.
3. In the behavior category of the properties, set the **Allow Drop** property to **True**.
4. From the project tab, select **add new data source**. A window will open and letting you choose the datasource.
5. Choose the database, then choose next a data set and then create a new connection if you don't have one.
6. Choose the table you want to use in your form by checking all or some of its fields.
7. Click finish button. In the View menu of VS, choose `Other windows` then choose `database explorer`. The purpose of choosing database explorer is to see if the database is connected or not.
8. Simply click on the refresh icon in the database explorer to connect using the database connection.
9. Now select again the `View` menu once more and choose `Other Windows`, then `Data Sources`.
10. You will be able to see the table you chosen in the data source window that opened.
11. Simply highlight the fields you want from the data source window table and drag and drop into your form. You will get the job done by linking automatically the table fields to the form you created.

Note: Always keep watching, while you are doing this, the database explorer window, just in case the connection to database has dropped due to any problem.

I hope this works for you.
Kind regards

Ashraf Sada

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to bind datagrid to dataset is simple drag n drop DataGridView control from Toolbox to your form and set it up in Tasks menu (triangle in the upper left corner). There will be "Choose data source" option where you can choose existing data source or create new via "Add project data source". Selecting data source for grid will automatically create new DataSet control and DataSetBindingSource control.

You can also find "how to" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)

Comment: Hi No no no, I have a Data Source in my left hand side of the VS and I have a dataset underneath.  I have seen in a video that the developer dragged and dropped it in winform by configuring it was either Datagrid or Details. It is possible to do, I am JUST TRYUNG TO REPLICATE WHATS SHOWN IN VIDEO